# Is it possible to show two different databases documents in one xpage view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have two address book in different server India and US(Both are cross certified).
I have one application(for example App A). I am using name picker in this application.
Can I able show both address books names in one view Panel in App A and do a search.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just now my colleague suggested me one possible solution. like getting the values and merge and show in Repeat control(merge document collection or view entries.) I have been working that . Is there any other solution for this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use a bean to hold the values. This allows you to cache values, so you don't fall victim of network latency. If inside that bean your store is a TreeMap or TreeSet sorting is fully automatic

Comment: Thanks stwissel . I am not aware about TreeMap or Treeset. I will learn and do that. fortunately I have weekend(enough time) to do R &D.

Comment: As stwissel suggessted, because this is name picker , we need use Managed beans to hold the values and do it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I just created globalnames.nsf which is getting all necessary fields from all address books. My application now directly refers global address book. This works fine. I am running the agent(scheduled) every day.